# Flutter Android InAppWebView camera and microphone blocked

Tags: android, flutter

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Route"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child:InAppWebView(
         //
          initialUrl:"https://user.djanah.com/invitation.php?hash=97200e406935bb896ccd6d799220f9aa",

          androidOnPermissionRequest: (InAppWebViewController c, String o,List<String> r)async{
              return PermissionRequestResponse(resources: r,action: PermissionRequestResponseAction.GRANT);

          },

          onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
            this._webViewController = controller;
          },

          onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {

              this.url = url;
          },
          onLoadStop: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {
           // status = true;
          },
          onWindowFocus: (controller) => {},
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add some context to what you are trying to achieve with the code. Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sorry.  but it has been resolved already .